# Extract Multiple Columns from Dataframe and Return NaN for Columns that do not Exist

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I am trying to extract multiple columns from a data frame such as below. I want to identify the columns needed by calling their names and return NaN for columns that do not exist in the data frame.

```py
data_1 = {'host_identity_verified':['t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t'],
      'neighbourhood':['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q'],

      'neighbourhood_cleansed':['Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West',
                                'Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West'],
     'neighbourhood_group_cleansed': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
      'latitude':[ 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719, 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
```

I know of this method to get one columns:

```py
x = df_1.get('neighbourhood_cleansed', pd.Series(index=df_1.index, name='neighbourhood_cleansed', dtype='object'))
```

But I can only get one column using this method at a time.

I want to do something like:

```py
columns_needed = [['host_identity_verified', 'neighbourhood', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'price']]

# x= some code to get me the columns above and return NaN for columns such as 'longitude' and 'price.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `reindex` function will create `naan` columns and extract the columns you need:

```py
df_1.reindex(['host_identity_verified', 'neighbourhood', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'price'], axis=1)
```